# Literature to learn thermodynamics coming from a statistical physics background

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I would like to read a book which rigorously defines what in applied thermodynamics is called "heat" and gives a proper derivation of the laws of thermodynamics from quantum statistics and the principle of Von Neumann entropy maximization.

I do not want a book which covers thermodynamics and then a bit of statistical physics, but the other way around. It should be on the same level of rigor as for example a graduate course on quantum mechanics would be.

Comment: Do you mean starting with statmech and then taking ensemble averages to recover the typical, macroscopic thermodynamic quantities?

Comment: @honeste_vivere yes, pretty much.

Comment: I found this to be very helpful in understanding fluid/thermodynamic limits and other ensemble averaging consequences:  https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1979RPPh...42.1937P/abstract

Comment: As my professor says, most of the research or written work is done because we feel the need for it. Maybe you could write up a book based on your requirement by compiling many references from research literature!

Comment: @AshwinBalaji I don't think anyone would want to read such a book written by an undergraduate haha

Comment: you would be a doctorate by the time you end up completing the book. or at least I would read it if it is loaded with citations to research literature ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part II of my online book

A. Neumaier and D. Westra, [Classical and Quantum Mechanics via Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019) (2011 version)

does precisely that. While it starts off with a chapter giving an axiomatic treatment of phenomenological thermodynamic, the next three chapters rederive all formulas (including the three laws of thermodynamics) in a rigorous way from quantum statistical mechanics, with properly formulated theorems and proofs.

As background one needs a good knowledge of linear algebra and of linear operators in Hilbert spaces, and a basic understanding of quantum mechanics. All statistical mechanics needed is developed from scratch.